# Xcode Pods functions not found in ModuleName-Swift.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, objective-c-swift-bridge

Because of a constraining library, I need to use Objective-C files in my Swift project.

So, I added the import module-Swift.h in my .m file.

It finds it without any issues.

The problem come from the auto-generated module-Swift.h" file.

I have a lot of errors, mainly from classes and protocols coming from Pods.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any config to fix this issue ?

Comment: are u added #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> this

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Where should I add this line ? In the objective-C file that use my Swift functions ?

Comment: Before that u create a bridging header ,below is my answer and add this #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> in that header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to Kavitha Madhu, I found the solution !**

For those who encounter the same issue:

If you want to use Swift classes and functions in you Objective-C code.

But, some of you Swift functions use Pods protocols and delegates.

You need to add in your Objective-C code the import of the pods headers that contain these protocols and delegates.

For example, if your module-Swift.h **doesn't find "SlideNavigationControllerDelegate"**, you need to **add in the Objective-C** file (which use "module-Swift.h") the line: 

**`#import <iOS_Slide_Menu/SlideNavigationController.h>`**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use objective c files in swift project, bridge the Objective files.

1)Create a new header file and name it like "your project name-Bridging-Header.h". The file must be saved to your project folder

2)Select your xcode project -> select your build target -> select build settings -> click the "all" option at the top -> search for Swift Compiler - General

3)Select **Objective-C Bridging Header** and  give the path as **$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h**

4)Finally add your objective files into the header file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer ! However, that's the opposite of what I want. I need to use Swift function in Objective-C code.